# Function to Sort an Array, Insert a Value into that Array and Return the Lowest Index

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am working on a JavaScript challenge that asks you to write a function to: "Return the lowest index at which a value (second argument) should be inserted into a sorted array (first argument). For example, `where([1,2,3,4], 1.5)` should return `1` because it is greater than `1 (0th index)`, but less than `2 (1st index)`."

The hint indicates to use a built-in "`.sort()`" method that I am unfamiliar with before this challenge. below is what I have so far and I think I am far off.

```
function where(arr, num) {
  arr.push(num).sort(function(a,b){return a-b;});
  return arr.indexOf(num);
}

console.log(where([40, 60], 50)); // returns "unexpected identifier"
```

Comment: `push` returns the new length of the array and not the array itself. You can’t sort a length.

Comment: What is the method I am looking for that would add the parameter 'num' to the end of the 'arr' and then allow me to sort that 'arr'? Is my 'sort' method implemented correctly to sort my array? @Xufox

Comment: Simply split the two statements! First `arr.push(num)`, then `arr.sort(…)`. Yes, the `sort` function looks okay.

Comment: I was just going to say never mind the natural conclusion is split the statements and call 'arr' the second time. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As rightly put by @Xufox, `push` returns the new length of the array and **not** the array itself.

Reorder your code as shown:

```
function where(arr, num) {
  arr.push(num); // Carry out push operation.
  arr.sort(function(a,b){return a-b;}); // Sort array. 
  return arr.indexOf(num); // Return index of 'num'.
}

console.log(where([40, 60], 50));
```

Answer (score 4):

Split the two statments.

```js
function where(arr, num) {
  arr.push(num);
  arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  });
  return arr.indexOf(num);
}

console.log(where([40, 60], 30)); // 0
console.log(where([40, 60], 50)); // 1
console.log(where([40, 60], 70)); // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function where(arr, num) {
  let index = arr.sort((x,y) => x-y)
                 .find(x => num <= x);

  return index === undefined? arr.length: arr.indexOf(index);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {  
  arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
});
  var i=0;
  while(num>arr[i])
    i++;
 return i;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.